# How to determine whether a Banalinga is genuine or not?

Tags: shiva, worship, shiva-lingam

Getting a [Banalinga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banalinga) (also known as Narmada Shiva Linga or  Narmadeswar Shiva linga) is quite easy these days.

You will get them in shops selling religious items. And, they are also sold on websites like ebay.

My question is how to determine whether the stone is really Lord Shiva or just any other lifeless stone?

Getting a Banalinga is important in the sense that since the Lord is already said to be  present  in it the elaborate procedures of pranapratistha are not needed to invoke the divine presence.

Comment: Best is to not buy from spurious sources. A true banalinga is retrieved from the depths of the river Narmada.

Comment: @moonstar2001 I actually want to know whether there is some test by which anyone can ascertain that the banalinga he is having is a genuine one.I once heard that if you get sound of water inside the linga while you shake it proves that it is a genuine one.

Comment: What do you mean by "stone is really Lord Shiva or just any other lifeless stone?"!

Comment: @Pandya What you have not understood in that statement?If you can elaborate i'll try to explain.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I read in a spiritual book(Soota Sanhita,Veermitrodaya) that there are two ways to determine whether a Banalinga is original or not.In the first rule you place it in one of the plates of a torsion balance and in the other place equivalent amount of uncooked rice and balance it after 5 minute and repeat for 7 times.If you feel Shivling is heavier than rice or vice versa then it's an original Banlinga ,or if not then it's a normal stone.if the amount of rice increases (or decreases) in every step with respect to previous one ,then it is a Banlinga or if not then it's a Narmadeswar shivling. If shivling gets heavier than rice then the Shivling is not proper for a householder and vice versa.According to the 2nd rule if you throw an original  Shivling in a flowing river after some time you will get it back.
        But being frank,
 I never tried them as the processes are a little complicated ,especially the 2nd one.I hope they will also work like the processes of testing Shilgram and Rudraksh work.[image: I have sent a page from 'Shila chakrarthabodhini',where the underlined descriptions support my words.]

Comment: I know about this book called Vira Mitradaya. I have one book on Lord Shiva which cites it at many places. Thanks for your answer..

Comment: BTW what's the exact name of the book and publisher? If i want to buy that is.

Comment: Is it Suta Samhita which is part of Skanda Purana?

Comment: I did not read Soota Sanhita separately .I read a book called "Shila Chakrarthabodhini" by Harakumar Thakur. The Sanskrit book describes different types of Shalgram , Narmadeswar and Banlinga and how they should be worshiped and many more.But it's a rare book and perhaps you may not collect it in a published form. The book which I have is written in Bengali alphabet. You may also read the very famous book " Tapabhumi Narmada" to get more information about this topic.

Comment: Suta sanhita is a part of Skanda Purana.please check here.https://archive.org/details/SutaSamhita-volume1...

Comment: To be clear: we weigh it and after 5 minutes or so the weight should seem to have increased is it?

Comment: @S.Majumder Can u tell me the name of the Bengali book u read these details in? Please tell the name of the book, the author and the publisher..

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/4732/rickross Sure,it is 'Shila Chakrarthabodhini'. But as I mentioned before, it is very difficult to get the book in published form.the book I had is  actually a Sanskrit book but written in Bengali alphabet and the book is basically a collection of information about Shivling and Shalagram ,collected from different authentic Sanskrit books (Sastra).You may also read 'Tapabhumi Narmada' by Shailendranarayan Ghosalsastri ,which is originally a Bengali book but translated in different languages including Hindi and English to get more information.

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/4133/user1952500 According to the rule mentioned in "suta Sanhita'' the weight of Shivling should be increased ,decreased or  remain same.for the 1st case it is improper for a house holder, 2 nd case it is proper for him and for the last one it is an ordinary stone. But for both of the first two cases ,the shivling is original.

Comment: @S.Majumder Thanks for giving me the book name.. BTW ur book is nice (from which u've added the ss)..But is the translation not there? Or it is there in the next page?

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/4732/rickross No, there is no translation. It's purely a Sanskrit book but written in Bengali alphabet.Please read the underlined part as a proof of my theory.

Comment: Yes i can see that it's in Sanskrit but in Bengali characters... So, u can understand thoroughly Sanskrit? I can understand little but not fully..@S.Majumder Also, when u are replying to me then u have to use @rickross otherwise i won't be notified about ur reply..

Comment: @rickross I also don't understand Sanskrit very well, but this book is written in comparatively easy language.If I can collect any translated version of 'Shila Chakrarthabodhini"  I must inform you.

Comment: @S.Majumder Ok thanks a lot.. I will also inform my book shop about this book..let's see if they can get it..