# Some interesting facts about narmadeshwara shiva linga?

Tags: shiva-lingam, narmadeswar-shivling

I am thinking of buying a narmadeswar Shiva linga. Can anyone tell me what are the do’s and don’t s of this type of shiva linga and what should be done daily for the proper maintainable of this shiva linga.

Also if someone wants to buy a narmadeswar linga how to know that the linga is an original linga? Thank you.

Comment: You can buy Banalinga. You will get a real one. Fake ones are not found easily as far as my experience goes.

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/10699/4732

Comment: Better to keep the Banalinga on a Yoni Pitha (usually made of brass) in the north east corner of the Puja room.